# Microsoft Wireless Mouse not working correctly after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: mouse, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After upgrading to Windows 10 I am finding a weird issue with the Wireless Optical Mouse 5000.

Clicks (left and right) simply fail to register on some UI elements though it works fine in all non OS applications (e.g. right clicking in any area of the screen in Google Chrome works as expected and shows the popup menu).

I can left click the start button and the start menu shows up (and right click works too for the context menu). Mousing over items on the Start Menu works fine but neither left or right click do anything.

Similarly when I open the "Settings" app I need to use the keyboard to tab through the options as selecting with the mouse doesn't work.

Not all OS windows are affected. Windows Explorer still works fine for example. It appears to be the windows with a newer look.

The latest drivers available for my mouse [seem to be Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/d/wireless-optical-mouse-5000). I have installed this with no change.

Anyone any ideas on underlying cause and how I might resolve this?

---

Additional info.

1. After reboot no clicks work at all unless I press CTRL+ALT+DEL and then escape out of the screen shown. Then everything appears to work fine. (This was an issue pre-upgrade too that I just got used to).
2. I had also noticed for the last few weeks the mouse battery is running down very fast and I now have to charge it weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As owner of Wireless Laser Desktop 7000 (kbd+mouse), I can say that they were always working well even without those special drivers. Do those drivers add any value for you? (Not a rhetoric question.) As an advice:

1. Try connecting some generic mouse, whether it works correctly. If it has the same problem, it is not in your Wireless Optical Mouse (WOM).
2. If the problem is only with your WOM, deinstall its special drivers and try with generic ones. (Go this way about half a year, then check new version of WOM drivers available - if you will ever miss them.)

I cannot find your mouse in [catalog of currently offered Microsoft mice](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/mice) so it is not sure whether it will get drivers for Windows 10 or not. Perhaps you can try with Windows 10 drivers for similar mouse model (trial and error method).

P.S. Is your mouse the same as the one currently offered with Wireless Comfort Desktop 5000? (See **Keyboards** section.) Then there is a good chance of getting Windows 10 drivers sooner or later.

---

Based on what you said later, another cause can be (and actually was) minor mechanical issue with mouse button. This can either add random mouse clicks or randomly prevent clicks you made. It can be identified:

1. By mechanical testing of mouse buttons - do all of them provide standard mechanical feedback when pressed? Do they hold down (in Windows) the entire time you are actually holding them down?
2. By connecting another mouse. Seeing whether both mice behave in the same way is essential for learning where the problem comes from.

Comment: Thanks. I've added some more info about various mouse oddness that I was also getting pre upgrade. I hadn't included the info at first as on Win7 the mouse oddness was just a mild inconvenience and only affected things on startup - not ongoing. I suspect after reading [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9075972d-21e0-4040-9c5d-48d3c2deda7c/mouse-deselects-active-window-wont-respond-until-ctrl-alt-del) though that I may well find a button is stuck down. If so strange that it affects some UI controls differently than others.

Comment: Yep - can confirm the left hand button on the side of the mouse ("back button?") doesn't make a clicking sound at all when pressed and seems to be stuck. Will try and get it unstuck and see if that resolves the Win10 specific issues too.

Comment: I managed to prise that button loose and it has now resolved the issue. Sorry there was no way you could have identified this issue from the original information. Please consider incorporating it into your answer and I'll accept. The description of symptons may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i had problems with MS keyboard dropping characters and ms mouse being very jerky after upgrading to win 10 from win 7 but as soon as i installed microsoft keyboard and mouse centre, and rebooted, all was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did the Windows 10 upgrade.  Everything went will, except for this mouse issue.  The mouse would just stop working.  I could do a CTL-ALT-DEL, and a switch users (back to myself actually), and the mouse would start working again.

I did a reinstall of Windows 10, I removed the wireless transceiver, I rebooted many times.

Nothing above worked.

I finally fixed this problem by going into Device Manager, Human Interface Devices (HID), and rolled back the Microsoft USB Mouse Input Device.

It seems to be working now.